# Weekday jQuery UI Tabs open on current day

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, weekday

I have weekday jQuery UI tabs as follows which I want to open on the current weekday:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="monday.php">Monday</a></li>
    <li><a href="tuesday.php">Tuesday</a></li>
    <li><a href="wednesday.php">Wednesday</a></li>
    <li><a href="thursday.php">Thursday</a></li>
    <li><a href="friday.php">Friday</a></li>
    <li><a href="saturday.php">Saturday</a></li>
    <li><a href="sunday.php">Sunday</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I want the tabs to open on the current day of the week, I know something like this works:

```
.eq((new Date().getDay() || 7) - 1).click();
```

But can't get it to work and would appreciate some help. Also, I would like the tab for the current day to display the word 'Today' instead of the weekday.

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks,

Brendon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to [`select`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select) the tab matching the current day:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', ((new Date().getDay() || 7) - 1));
```

and you could modify the text of the active tab with the following:

```
$('#tabs .ui-state-active a').text('Today');
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="monday.php">Monday</a></li>
        <li><a href="tuesday.php">Tuesday</a></li>
        <li><a href="wednesday.php">Wednesday</a></li>
        <li><a href="thursday.php">Thursday</a></li>
        <li><a href="friday.php">Friday</a></li>
        <li><a href="saturday.php">Saturday</a></li>
        <li><a href="sunday.php">Sunday</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('#tabs').tabs('select', ((new Date().getDay() || 7) - 1));
$('#tabs .ui-state-active a').text('Today');
```

and needs the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/874U7/)