# Select Active Tab By Date

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

This question was posed about selecting the active tab by weekday https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681679/1339863.

I'm sure this can be done for the month as well, but I have searched and haven't been able to find the proper application.  I'm so new to jquery I can't figure out how to alter the code to suit my needs.  Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

you can adapt the previous code in the stackoverflow archive, just you need to extract months from date, use this code:

```
var date = new Date();
var months = date.getMonth();
```